# Я новичок в C#. Пишу простенький калькулятор, ошибка CS1503

Tags: c#

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int num1, num2, d, r;
            Console.WriteLine("Первое число:");
            num1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Первое число:");
            num2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Действие:" +
                "1 - сложение" +
                "2 - вычитание" +
                "3 - умножение" +
                "4 - деление" +
                "5 - целочисленное деление");
            d = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            if (d == 1)
            {
                r = Convert.ToInt32(Console.WriteLine(num1 + num2));
            }
            if (d == 2)
            {
                r = Convert.ToInt32(Console.WriteLine(num1 - num2));
            }
            if (d == 3)
            {
                r = Convert.ToInt32(Console.WriteLine(num1 * num2));
            }
            if (d == 4)
            {
                r = Convert.ToInt32(Console.WriteLine((float)num1 / num2));
            }
            if (d == 5)
            {
                r = Convert.ToInt32(Console.WriteLine(num1 / num2));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Не могу найти ошибку :(

Comment: какую ошибку? приведите **текст** ошибки прямо в вопросе, нажав [edit]

Comment: Вам надо бы еще добавить номер строки в которой ошибка.(На будущее)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (d == 1)
{
    r = num1 + num2;
    Console.WriteLine(r);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогли

Answer (score 3):

Для того что бы вывести какой-либо текст в консоль, вам не нужно преобразовывать в какой-либо тип. Странно выглядит, когда вы конвертируете вывод в число. Вы выводите и конвертируете. Так не получиться. Так что Ваш код должен иметь вот такой вид:

Метод `Console.WriteLine()` выводит данные переданные в аргумент в окно консоли.
Может Вы хотели сократить таким образом код, но сделали неправильно. Это можно понять исходя из окна с ошибкой:

> Не удалось преобразовать "void" в "object".

`void` это ключевое слово, которое указывает, что метод не возвращает никаких значений. Пустоту грубо говоря. Вот как раз метод `Console.WriteLine()` и возвращает `void`. Узнать какой тип вернет метод, можно узнать если навести на метод курсор и увидеть примерно такой текст:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И Вы пытались конвертировать "пустоту" в `Int32`. На такое действие компилятор Вам указал, что такой трюк не провернуть. 
Самый короткий вариант который может быть это `Console.WriteLine(num1 + num2);`

Исходя из выше сказанного, Ваш код будет работать в вот таком виде:

```
int num1, num2, d;
Console.WriteLine("Первое число:");
num1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Первое число:");
num2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Действие:" +
    "1 - сложение" +
    "2 - вычитание" +
    "3 - умножение" +
    "4 - деление" +
    "5 - целочисленное деление");
d = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
if (d == 1)
{
    Console.WriteLine(num1 + num2);
}
if (d == 2)
{
    Console.WriteLine(num1 - num2);
}
if (d == 3)
{
    Console.WriteLine(num1 * num2);
}
if (d == 4)
{
    Console.WriteLine((float)num1 / num2);
}
if (d == 5)
{
    Console.WriteLine(num1 / num2);
}
```

**Удачи в изучении C#**

<kbd>Aqua</kbd>

Comment: Вам тоже спасибо.

Comment: Приятно было помочь, хоть и поздно...